# How can I use CommonJS modules with Oracle's new Nashorn JS Engine?

Tags: commonjs, nashorn

I'm looking for a module system for Nashorn. From what I can tell, CommonJS is the way to go concerning modules for JS. I have looked through the list ([here](http://www.commonjs.org/impl/) and [here](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS#Implementations)) and have found little in the way of a CommonJS implementation for Java.

[Narwhal](https://github.com/tlrobinson/narwhal) is no longer active and it's [documentation](http://narwhaljs.org/) is no longer hosted on GitHub. Is there an existing CommonJS implementation which supports Java or should I start a new project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked a very similar question on the Nashorn mailing list a little while back, here's Sundar's (Nashorn Engineer) reply:

> From: A. Sundararaj​an
>
> To: nashorn-dev@openjdk.java.net
>
> I forgot to add. Nashorn does not contain any builtin module system. 
>   But, if a module system is pure JS + Java, it must be possible to run
>   on  nashorn.
>
> Nashorn supports "load" (loads scripts from URL, File, resources) and 
>   "loadWithNewGlobal" (loads script but into a fresh global scope) 
>   primitives in addition to the good old 'eval'. So, it should be
>   possible  for any module system to be implemented on top of nashorn in
>   pure JS or  perhaps with a bit of Java code.
>
> -Sundar

Answer (score 18):

Have a look at jvm-npm here https://github.com/nodyn/jvm-npm. This project is used by nodyn as the CommonJS module system. It is NPM-aware, meaning you can load modules directly from NPM, but it does not provide any of the Node.js API.

Here is a simple example usage:

```
$ npm install pegjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pegjs
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pegjs
pegjs@0.8.0 node_modules/pegjs
$ jrunscript
nashorn> typeof require
undefined
nashorn> load('./jvm-npm.js')
nashorn> typeof require
function
nashorn> var PEG = require('pegjs');
nashorn> typeof PEG
object
```

It is primarily all Javascript, but the actual loading of files from the filesystem and such is done using Java.

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking for such an implementation for a while. I've been using a little patched version of [Rhino-Require](https://github.com/micmath/Rhino-Require). Although Rhino claimed to be CommonJS compatible, AFAIK, it implemented only modules and not packages (package.json) can't be parsed.
[RingoJS](http://ringojs.org/) should be compatible. But Nashorn will never be [see](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nashorn-dev/2012-December/000014.html).

Laterly, Oracle announced project Avatar which relies on [Avatar.js](https://java.net/projects/avatar-js) or [here](https://avatar-js.java.net/). It's the official project of what was unofficially called Node.jar. But as of now, you have to compile it by yourself. The project is very young.

Another very young project is [Nodyn](http://nodyn.io/) which relies on dyn.js.

So, if understood well, CommonJs should work with avatar-js and nodyn, but those two are still pretty young. I don't understand why avatar-js in not fully distributed along with nashorn though.

A kind of solution would be to add a CommonJS compatibility script like the one for Rhino which adds importClass/importPackage ([mozilla_compat.js](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~sundar/8007286/webrev.00/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/resources/mozilla_compat.js-.html)) which would add CommonJS compatibility into nashorn, kind of Rhino-Require shim thoroughly tested.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same need, and I used [jvm-npm](https://github.com/nodyn/jvm-npm) for a while, but I needed something that would work even without allowing usage of Java packages inside JavaScript, so I wrote my own version here: https://github.com/coveo/nashorn-commonjs-modules

It's implemented entirely in Java and supports loading modules from elsewhere than the filesystem (Java resources, a custom database, etc.)

It's published on Maven Central if someone wants to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There's also nashorn-require, you can get that off of github too. I've used it, I was able to do

```
        engine.eval(reader("src/main/javascript/nashorn-require.js"),bindings);
        engine.eval("var initRequire = load('src/main/javascript/nashorn-require.js');",bindings);
        engine.eval("initRequire({mainFile : 'src/main/javascript/foo', debug : true})", bindings);
        engine.eval("var babel = require('babel');",bindings);
```

and then transpile JSX React components to ES5 with

```
        Buffer input = findTemplateSource(fileLocation,context);
        bindings.put("input",input.toString());
        result = engine.eval("babel.transform(input,{ presets: ['react', 'es2015'] }).code;",bindings);
```

Then when I pulled react and react-dom into my browser and loaded the resulting js components, things worked fine, so I'm sure Babel was perfectly happy, though I'm not sure about if it will find 3rd-party plugins or not...