# Solr DataImportHandler using ScriptTransformer: JavaScript functionality severely limited

Tags: javascript, solr, dataimporthandler

I'm using a simple ScriptTransformer `<script>` in my db-data-config.xml DataImportHandler. I'd like to decode htmlentities and found I should be using `he` module. [Downloaded the zip](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) and extracted in `conf\lib`. This is part of my script:

```
var he = require('./lib/he-master/he.js');
function removeSpecialCharacters(text) {
     if (typeof text !== 'string') {
          return text;
     }
     return he.decode(text);
}
```

But I get the error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "require" is not defined in <eval>
```

Why does nothing work out of the box (like JS `require` function) and how do I solve this?

It's cheaper to pay than use open source because nothing works out of the box. It takes ages of troubleshooting ($) before something with a little bit of an advanced functionality works.

also tried

```
eval(readFile('./lib/he-master/he.js');
```

But it's the same story: nothing is included out of the box with Solr:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "readFile" is not defined in <eval>
```

Comment: Note that the script processors and transformers written in javascript run on a javascript engine called Nashorn (by default as of java 8, until java 7 it was Rhino, and you can still specify another one). Nashorn is used as an embedded scripting engine that run inside Java applications like Solr, but it doesn't have any module system built in like node's `require()`. However, you can still `load()` a third-party script that implements the CommonJS specification, @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500141/how-can-i-use-commonjs-modules-with-oracles-new-nashorn-js-engine

Comment: @EricLavault I'm still having issues. In `./conf/db-data-config.xml` I use a js script with `load('./lib/jvm-npm.js');`. `I have ./lib/jvm-npm.js` so lib and conf ara sibling folders (is that right?).
`jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: TypeError: Cannot load script from ./lib/jvm-npm.js`

Comment: "It's cheaper to pay than use open source because nothing works out of the box. It takes ages of troubleshooting ($) before something with a little bit of an advanced functionality works.". Nobody is forcing you. Either fix it yourself or pay the required amount to get what you want. It's also worth nothing that the dataimporthandler has been removed in Solr 9. It's also not meant as a complete JavaScript runtime - in that case, write your indexing code in node instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh Sure nobody is forcing me... I'm just saying if I (and thousands of first-timers before me) hadn't had the same kind of never-ending problems with Debian (nothing works), word would've spread to millions and Microsoft would've been bankrupt by now as everyone would be on Linux (and thousands more programmers would be contributing).
(To be fair I tried Mint afterwards and that did work just fine out of the box.)

Comment: @MatsLindh If you really don't want to include anything, a 100 line getting-started readme could've saved so many people hundreds of hours

Comment: You are asking your question with a lot of assumptions that you have not explained. I have no idea why you even tried to require anything in ScriptTransformer, without clarifying where you found such advice or documentation. We don't know what version of Solr you are on and what you are even trying to achieve. It could pay to frame your question with more context and without all the negative bias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figgered out that the solution is to use `load` and absolute path:

```
load('C:\\solr-8.11.3\\server\\solr\\db\\lib\\he-master\\he.js');
```